# Triple Boot Ubuntu, Kali Linux & Windows 10 Grub issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I used to run dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10 with no conflicts at all for over a year now. The Grub Boot-loader was Ubuntu's.

I decided to install Kali Linux to fulfill triple booting for educational purposes. The issue is the default Grub loader now is Kali's and it's only showing Ubuntu & Kali Linux.

After trying Gparted and disk listing I realized that windows 10 is still there safely.

I remember choosing to install Kali Linux's grub boot-loader at the installation which said that it detected Ubuntu & Windows 7. Then it over-wrote Ubuntu's grub and windows isn't accessible anymore.

I am new to Kali but I know one thing. I would probably get windows 10 Back if I can install Ubuntu's boot-loader back as the default grub. Any idea how to perform this? Or what would the best solution be with regard to this case?

I also had UEFI as the default boot method from the BIOS but switching it with Legacy back and forth makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to run a live cd of Ubuntu and install boot-repair.
Open the terminal and copy and paste the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

After successfully adding and updating the repository type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

There you can solve your issues related to boot.

Or try it with Super GRUB 2 disk.

You can download it from [here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/).

Then install it in a usb using [Unetbootin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unetbootin/)
Now you could restart your system and make sure it is set in the boot option menu.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the first solution did the trick, I got the three OSes working smooth now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use boot-repair you dont actually have to install it. You can boot from the boot-repair live CD. I have had good results in the past using the live CD, simply selecting the automatic repair option.

However, why not try this. Boot into your Ubuntu and re-installgrub from a command line.

Assuming you have one HDD /dev/sda

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

You might also have to update grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```

That should install Ubuntus grub to the MBR.

Answer (score 2):

Others have suggested using Boot Repair, and this may well work. If it doesn't, you could try my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which eliminates several (mostly minor) GRUB-related problems when dealing with multiple distributions. rEFInd is also more reliable than GRUB at booting Windows. You can try rEFInd using a USB flash drive or CD-R (versions of both are available from its downloads page) risk-free, and if that works, install the rEFInd Debian package or PPA in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Well i had the same problem but instead of windows i coudn't find my freshly installed kali linux option. Well what you can do is use GRUB Customizer just install it in ubuntu or kali and then use it to add the windows/linux option and then save it. Also ,if its showing all the boot options just save it and then reboot ,it should be there. Hope, this works for you.